# How can we upload m3u8 file and corresponding ts file to amazon s3 bucket using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to upload the generated m3u8 file and corresponding ts file to s3 bucket but problem is how can i upload all .ts file also along with m3u8.

my ffmpeg code is

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const ffmpegInstaller = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg')


ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path)

ffmpeg('uploads/malayalam.mp4').addOptions([

'-c:a',
  'aac',
  '-ar',
  '48000',
  '-b:a',
  '128k',
  '-c:v',
  'h264',
  '-profile:v',
  'main',
  '-crf',
  '20',
  '-g',
  '48',
  '-keyint_min',
  '48',
  '-sc_threshold',
  '0',
  '-b:v',
  '2500k',
  '-maxrate',
  '2675k',
  '-bufsize',
  '3750k',
  '-hls_time',
  '4',
  '-hls_playlist_type',
  'vod',
  '-hls_segment_filename',
  'uploads/video/720p_%03d.ts'

]).output('uploads/video/output.m3u8').on('end',(err,data)=>{
  console.log(data)
  console.log('end')
}).run()
```

generated m3u8 file directory look like

[image]

i used this code to upload m3u8 file

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

  const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId:"secretid",
    secretAccessKey:"accesskey"
  })

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("uploads/video/output.m3u8");


  const params = {
    Body: fileContent,
    Bucket:"5am5pm",
    Key:"output.m3u8"
  }

  s3.upload(params,(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
```

But it uploading only the m3u8 file **how can i upload .ts file too . if someone help it is very thankfull**

Comment: Loop over the files and upload individually

Comment: there is no other method. is there any method directly upload after m3u8 file created

Comment: Why would you expect uploading one file to also upload other, unnamed files?

Comment: beacause for playing the m3u8 file .ts also needed

Comment: i used the ffmpeg for live streaming

Comment: I understand that you want all these TS files uploaded but you're asking the SDK to upload a single file (output.m3u8). How can the SDK know that you also want other files? You need to upload them one by one (or potentially write a function that enumerates all files in a folder and upload those, if that makes sense for your use case).

Comment: do you know how can we read that m3u8 file from s3 bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, just loop over the files and upload individually:

```
fs.readdir('uploads/video', (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Failed to list directory: ' + err);
    } 

    files.forEach(file => {
        const params = {
            Body: fs.createReadStream('uploads/video/' + file);,
            Bucket:"5am5pm",
            Key: file
        }

        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: do you know how can we play this m3u8 file by video.js